# people use thank you instead accepting answer

Tags: discussion

I have notice that there is some people who uses thank you instead of accepting an answer

https://magento.stackexchange.com/users/45390/er-sarvesh-v-tiwari?tab=questions

This guys has 38 question and not a single answer is accepted

I have recently give one answer to this user

[How do I” Pass variable between .phtml files?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/150064/how-do-i-pass-variable-between-phtml-files/150213#150213)

He uses thank you instead of accepting my answer.

What should we do with this type of situation, and it is also not good thing for MagentoSE

I think once they got solution they need to accept someones answer or Else they have to put their own answers

Comment: *I am your father* :D

Comment: thanks you :) posting this question :D

Comment: I'm just starting to answer questions on here and am also noticing that marking an answer accepted seems to confuse people :)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

One thing is clear. You cannot force people to accept answers if they don't want to.
But you can encourage them (but avoid nagging) by leaving a comment under the question or under the answer that should be accepted telling the OP to mark the answer as accepted.
That't the best you can do about it.

Comment: Yes I have done the same But not get the reply from that man and even he is not accepting anyones answers , its strange thing that I have notice

Comment: ok. I will send him a message, but that doesn't mean it will get the problem solved.

Comment: Ok, thank you  I appreciate your quick response

Comment: That's their choice to either accept or give only thank you.  
Marius

Answer (score 6):

It would be nice from stackexchange to send a reminder to those users like Amazon or eBay does?

[image]

:-)